# Is there a better way to determine day in future using integer values

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, integer

Here is the problem:

> If the int values [0,7) (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) refer to Monday through
> Sunday, and today is Monday, what day of the week will it be in 999
> days?

Here is how I solved it:

```
import datetime
 
#Capture the First Date
day1 = datetime.date(2021, 1, 25)
print('day1:', day1.ctime())

# Capture the Second Date
day2 = datetime.date(2023, 10, 21)
print('day2:', day2.ctime())

# Find the difference between the dates
print('Number of Days:', day1-day2)
```

Returns:

```
day1: Mon Jan 25 00:00:00 2021
day2: Sat Oct 21 00:00:00 2023
Number of Days: -999 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions about making code better are more in the scope of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you  @niamulbengali  for your polite correction. I'll take note for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timedelta` to add `n` days from your "start date":

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

current = date.today()
future = current + timedelta(days=999)

print(f"{current=}", current.weekday(), current.strftime("%A"))
print(f"{future=}", future.weekday(), future.strftime("%A"))
```

Output:

```
current=datetime.date(2021, 1, 24) 6 Sunday
future=datetime.date(2023, 10, 20) 4 Friday
```

`.weekday()` returns the day of the week as an integer.
`.strftime("%A")` will format a date object as a Weekday name.

Comment: could you please also explain how to get `day` from `datetime` object? OPs question is to find out day: *" `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` refer to Monday through Sunday, and today is Monday, **what day of the week will it be** in 999 days"*`

Comment: I imported the calendar and the defined a way to find the day:

def findDay(date): 
    day, month, year = (int(i) for i in date.split(' '))     
    dayNumber = calendar.weekday(year, month, day) 
    days =["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
                         "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 
    return (days[dayNumber]) 
  
# Driver program 
date = '20 10 2023'
print(findDay(date))

Results returned: 
(2023, 10, 20)
Friday